# Why does xargs -L yield the right format, while xargs -n doesn't?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, whitespace, xargs

Consider the following:

```
$ echo index.html* | xargs -L 1 ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeki zeki  17198 2011-05-03 23:18 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeki zeki  17198 2011-05-03 23:20 index.html.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeki zeki  17198 2011-05-03 23:21 index.html.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeki zeki 146589 2011-05-05 12:29 index.html.3
$ echo index.html* | xargs -n 1 ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeki zeki 17198 2011-05-03 23:18 index.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeki zeki 17198 2011-05-03 23:20 index.html.1
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeki zeki 17198 2011-05-03 23:21 index.html.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 zeki zeki 146589 2011-05-05 12:29 index.html.3
```

Why does the -n option yield an incorrect formatting? Just in case, I'm using bash under Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`-L` splits by lines; `echo` doesn't separate its output by lines but by spaces, so a single `ls -l` is run and that formats all the columns as a group.

`-n` splits by parameters; in the absence of `-L` or `-0`, the separator is whitespace (possibly modified by quoting), so each filename gets its own `ls -l` run and there is no way for the independent runs to coordinate column widths.

Answer (score 3):

The POSIX standard [mandates](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html):

> `-L`  *number*
>
> The utility shall be executed for each non-empty `number` **lines** of arguments from standard input. The last invocation of utility shall be with fewer lines of arguments if fewer than number remain. A **line** is considered to end with the first  unless the last character of the line is a `<blank>`; a trailing `<blank>` signals continuation to the next non-empty line, inclusive.
>
> `-n`  *number*
>
> Invoke utility using as many standard input **arguments** as possible, up to *number* (a positive decimal integer) arguments maximum.

(Emphasis added.) Since `echo *` produces a single line, `xargs -L 1` just feeds all of the filenames to `ls` at once, and only then can `ls` nicely align the columns.

(In other words, your first command is equivalent `ls -l index.html*`, except that it doesn't handle filenames containing blanks correctly.)

Answer (score 3):

**Minimal runnable example of how `-L` splits by lines and `-n` by whitespace**

This should clarify what [geekosaur said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527296/895245) further:

```
printf '1 2\n3 4\n' | xargs -L1 echo
```

splits by line and therefore is equivalent to:

```
echo 1 2
echo 3 4
```

which outputs:

```
1 2
3 4
```

However:

```
printf '1 2\n3 4\n' | xargs -n1 echo
```

splits on any whitespace, and is therefore equivalent to:

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
```

and produces instead:

```
1
2
3
4
```

**Also worth noting: trailing spaces make `-L` ignore the newline**

Not sure what is the rationale, but:

```
printf '1 2 \n3 4\n' | xargs -L1 echo
```

calls `echo` just once and produces:

```
1 2 3 4
```

because of that space after the `2`. This is documented on `man xargs`:

> `-L max-lines`
>
> Use at most max-lines nonblank input lines per command line.  Trailing blanks cause an input line to be logically continued on the next input line.  Implies `-x`.

**Portability**

As mentioned at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448290/are-l1-and-n-1-the-same-for-xargs/448379#448379 `-L` is slightly less portable as it is a XSI POSIX extension, while `-n` isn't.